# Errors when attempting to dynamically control element names during XML Serialization

Tags: c#, xml, xml-serialization

I've been researching online, including Stack Overflow, but either I'm missing something or the examples I've seen just don't apply to my situation.

I am receiving this error when I attempt to dynamically set the root and list item element names during XML Serialization.

```
XmlRoot and XmlType attributes may not be specified for the type
System.Collections.Generic.List`1[
  [XmlSerializationFailureExample.Controllers.MyClass, XmlSerializationFailureExample,
  Version=1.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=null]]
```

I've seen one rather old posting on [Microsoft's site](https://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/en-US/726317a0-aaff-468c-b099-f47227190bf3/misleading-error-message-from-xmlserializer-constructor?forum=asmxandxml) which states that the message ought to read: `Only XmlRoot and XmlType attributes may be specified...`. Sure enough, if I remove all overrides except XmlRoot and XmlType, the error is cleared, but then the rendered XML does not match my needs.

I am using the `XmlSerializer` Overrides constructor because I have to dynamically set the Root and first child element names. The same classes need to produce different XML element names in different situations. Though this sample has a meager two fields, the actual class being serialized has around 100 fields.

**So, how can I control the name of both the root element and the immediate child elements when directly serializing a `List<MyClass>` object?**

The objective is to get XML looking like this:

```xml
<ArrayOfPerson>
  <Person>
    <Name>John Doe</Name>
    <Age>57</Age>
  </Person>
  <Person>
    <Name>Doe, Jane</Name>
    <Age/>
  </Person>
</ArrayOfPerson>
```

By changing the override values, I should be able to generate XML like this from the same class:

```xml
<ArrayOfEmployee>
  <Employee>
    <Name>John Doe</Name>
    <Age>57</Age>
  </Employee>
  <Employee>
    <Name>Doe, Jane</Name>
    <Age/>
  </Employee>
</ArrayOfEmployee>
```

Here is some simplified code that demonstrates my problem. I used a basic MVC.Net app from Visual Studio 2013's templates for this example.

```cs
// GET api/SerializationTest
public ActionResult SerializationTest()
{
    var list = new List<MyClass> {
        new MyClass {Name = "John Doe", Age = 57},
        new MyClass {Name = "Doe, Jane"}
    };

    XmlAttributes xmlPerson = new XmlAttributes {
        XmlRoot = new XmlRootAttribute { ElementName = "Person" }
    };

    XmlAttributes xmlPersonList = new XmlAttributes {
        XmlRoot = new XmlRootAttribute { ElementName = "ArrayOfPerson" },
        XmlArrayItems = {
            new XmlArrayItemAttribute("Person",typeof(MyClass))
        },
    };

    XmlAttributeOverrides overrides = new XmlAttributeOverrides();
    overrides.Add(typeof(MyClass), xmlPerson);
    overrides.Add(typeof(List<MyClass>), xmlPersonList);

    return new XmlResult(
        list,
        "TestFile.xml",
        overrides
    );
}
```

The example class being serialized. The actual class has around 100 properties.

```cs
public class MyClass
{
    public string Name { get; set; }
    public int? Age { get; set; }
}
```

**Update 1**

If I encapsulate my `List<MyClass>` in another class and annotate with attributes as below, I can get the XML I want. But how do I do this dynamically, as the specified element names must vary at runtime?

```cs
[XmlRoot(ElementName = "ArrayOfPerson")]
public class MyCollection
{

    [XmlElement(ElementName = "Person")]
    public List<MyClass> Items { get; set; }

}
```

**End of Update 1**

The `XmlResult` type derives from the built-in `ActionResult` and contains the actual serialization logic. The class is intended to return a file rather than an HTML page.

```cs
public class XmlResult : ActionResult
{

    private string FileName { get; set; }
    private object ObjectToSerialize { get; set; }
    private XmlAttributeOverrides Overrides { get; set; }

    public XmlResult(object objectToSerialize, string fileName, XmlAttributeOverrides overrides)
    {
        ObjectToSerialize = objectToSerialize;
        FileName = fileName;
        Overrides = overrides;
    }

    public override void ExecuteResult(ControllerContext context)
    {
        HttpContext.Current.Response.Clear();
        HttpContext.Current.Response.AddHeader("content-control", "no-store, no-cache");
        HttpContext.Current.Response.AddHeader("content-disposition", "attachment;filename=" + FileName);
        HttpContext.Current.Response.ContentType = "text/xml";
        try
        {
            if (ObjectToSerialize != null)
            {
                var xs = new XmlSerializer(ObjectToSerialize.GetType(), Overrides);
                xs.Serialize(HttpContext.Current.Response.Output, ObjectToSerialize);
            }
        }
        catch (Exception ex)
        {
            HttpContext.Current.Response.Write("<error>" + ex + "</error>");
        }
        HttpContext.Current.Response.Flush();
        HttpContext.Current.Response.SuppressContent = true;
        HttpContext.Current.ApplicationInstance.CompleteRequest();
    }

}
```

Comment: If you want to parse dynamically, then use XML Linq instead of de-serialization.

Comment: Here is a good example of recursively parsing an XML.  The code takes an XML and loads into a treevew.

Comment: @jdweng I think you forgot to add the link to your comment. And, I'm looking to serialize POCO to XML, rather than the reverse.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Well, I was not able to make things as dynamic as I wanted, but this solution seems to work.

First, I made my class an abstract base class:

```cs
public abstract class MyBaseClass
{

    public string Name { get; set; }

    public int? Age { get; set; }

}
```

Then I created derived classes for each of the XML element names I wanted:

```cs
public class Person : MyBaseClass { }

public class Employee : MyBaseClass { }
```

Then it was a simple matter of making sure I used the correct derived classes within my controller action methods.

```cs
public ActionResult SerializePersonCollectionByXml()
{
    var list = new List<Person> {
        new Person {Name = "John Doe", Age = 57},
        new Person {Name = "Doe, Jane"}
    };

    return new XmlResult(
        list,
        "PersonCollectionByXml.xml"
    );
}

// GET api/SerializationTest
public ActionResult SerializeEmployeeCollectionByXml()
{
    var list = new List<Employee> {
        new Employee {Name = "John Doe", Age = 57},
        new Employee {Name = "Doe, Jane"}
    };

    return new XmlResult(
        list,
        "EmployeeCollectionByXml.xml"
    );
}
```

Of course, things were a bit more complicated in the real application...
The technique above allowed me to keep all the properties and methods in the base class and just use the derived class to get the desired XML element names.

The real app was choosing the `Person` or `Employee` class at run-time, based upon an input parameter to the action method. Further, the logic was buried within another set of classes with an inheritance structure mirroring the classes. Since .Net 4.6 does not yet support covariance with generic types (only interfaces and delegates), I had to go through a few more gyrations to get the right return values from the inner logic before I could return them via the XmlResult class.

Example:

Internal Service Classes:

```cs
public abstract class ServiceBase<TRecord> : IDisposable where TRecord : MyBaseClass
{

    public abstract List<TRecord> Search(SearchParams p);

}

public class ServicePerson : ServiceBase<Person>
{

    public override List<Person> Search(SearchParams p)
    {
        var result = base.Search(p);
        // for example only, just used a simple cast; more complex operation may be required.
        return result.Select(r => (Person)r).ToList();
    }

}

public class ServiceEmployee : ServiceBase<Employee>
{

    public override List<Employee> Search(SearchParams p)
    {
        var result = base.Search(p);
        // for example only, just used a simple cast; more complex operation may be required.
        return result.Select(r => (Employee)r).ToList();
    }

}
```

Controller's action method:

```cs
public ActionResult Search(Guid apiKey, SearchParams p)
{
    try
    {
        if (p.UsePerson)
        {
            using (var service = new ServicePerson())
            {
                List<Person> result = service.Search(p);
                return XmlResult(result, "PersonList.xml");
            }
        }
        using (var service = new ServiceEmployee())
        {
            List<Employee> result = service.Search(p);
            return XmlResult(result, "EmployeeList.xml");
        }
    }
    catch (Exception ex)
    {
        // log error
    }
}
```